# Why is gunicorn calling sys.exit(1)?

Tags: docker, gunicorn, python-internals, pythoninterpreter

Gunicorn is sometimes crashing my server, actually  exiting the Python interpreter with `sys.exit(1)`! Why is this? Note that the failure is not always at the same point. In the two cases shown below, there is a different last codeline before  gunicorn's `exit`.  This code running here is openpyxl , which should not be causing interpreter shutdown!

Is the server running out of memory? Some other cause?

(This is Flask on Gunicorn on Docker in Google Container Engine.)

Case 1

```
  File "/virtualenv_for_docker/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/base.py", line 166, in __set__
    super(Bool, self).__set__(instance, value)
  File "/virtualenv_for_docker/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 196, in handle_abort
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
```

Case 2

```
  File "/virtualenv_for_docker/lib/python3.7/site-packages/openpyxl/descriptors/serialisable.py", line 164, in __eq__
    def __eq__(self, other):
  File "/virtualenv_for_docker/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 196, in handle_abort
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
```

Comment: Looks like the server is catching a SIGABRT: https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/master/gunicorn/workers/base.py#L169-L195

Comment: Hello. I am currently facing the same issue, can you please tell what was your solution?
I tried increasing the timeout parameter value but still faced the same issue. Running Flask + Gunicorn on Azure Container Instance. My processing time isn't that long either.

Comment: The solution is to ensure that the request completes faster. However, if "processing time isn't that long" then your problem may be different.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

As wrote @maxm the server is catching a `SIGABRT`, that call generally [happens on timeout](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/927fb2ba02b4bbc8e1c64fc0139fc0d91d72d188/gunicorn/arbiter.py#L487).

You should increase the timeout value or reduce the request processing time. Also [you can setup the signal handler](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/blob/91974f0f44080fdd6f2885832d101474671c4b9b/examples/example_config.py#L215) to try to log what happened in the worker after a timeout.

Comment: If you cannot reduce processing time, you can set a timeout for the function like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14924210/9070016)