# Django Gunicorn different type of timeout

Tags: django, heroku, timeout, gunicorn, sentry

I serve a Django app with Gunicorn (using Heroku) and Sentry for monitoring. I regularly receive 2 different types of timeout error on Sentry:

1. `SystemExit 1` in `gunicorn/workers/base.py` in `handle_abort` at line 201
2. `WORKER TIMEOUT (pid:12345)` at the Gunicorn level

For the second one, It produces H13 errors in Heroku which [according to the docs means](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/error-codes#h13-connection-closed-without-response):

> This error is thrown when a process in your web dyno accepts a connection but then closes the socket without writing anything to it.
> One example where this might happen is when a [Unicorn web server](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-unicorn) is configured with a timeout shorter than 30s and a request has not been processed by a worker before the timeout happens. In this case, Unicorn closes the connection before any data is written, resulting in an H13.

which is clear enough.

However for the `System Exit 1`, I read that it was a timeout in a [similar ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52993280/why-is-gunicorn-calling-sys-exit1) but I am not sure exactly what is the difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SystemExit is just the generic "stop process" signal, it could be that the same error is caught twice by Sentry (once thrown as exception, once logged with level=error).

Comment: That would explain a lot. I will double check to confirm this.

Comment: This is correct, for every System Exit I can match a WORKER TIMEOUT. Thanks !